# What does this python expression mean

Tags: python, operators, logic

I'm having some problems with the logic below. I was learning about the unittest module and came across this code.

```
def matches(self, date):

    return ((self.year and self.year == date.year or True) and
            (self.month and self.month == date.month or True) and
            (self.day and self.day == date.day or True) and
            (self.weekday and self.weekday == date.weekday() or True))
```

Which to me looks like it will always end up True. In discussing why the code doesn't work, this difference was discussed:

```
>>> c=1
>>> c and c == 2 or True
True
>>> c and c == (2 or True)
False
```

What is the logic for either of "c and c == 2 or True" vs "c and c == (2 or True)"

I known that "==" binds stronger than or, but I don't understand what the entire construct is trying to do. It being used to enable a wildcard. As a part, I guess I need explanation on how and works on numbers (I always thought about it in relation to True/False conditions.

What is the point of the "c and c" part of either expression?

Thanks,

Narnie

Comment: This looks like really horrible code TBH. Where did you get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I figured out what the author was trying to do.

The author likes python, but comes from a C background. He was trying to simulate a ternary operation as in:

```
bool ? true_value : false_value
```

The pythonic way of doing this is not

```
c and c == d or True
```

stuff, but to use this as of python 2.5 and up:

```
result = x if a > b else y
```

If using a lower version of python, do:

```
result = (y, x)[a>b]
```

Comment: Indeed - prior to Python 2.5, when the inline "if" for Python was introduced, I saw people recommending code like the above (instead of the "use the bool value to index a tuple" like in the last example)

Comment: Note that the `x and expr or y ` way of doing it can fail expetacularly, in hard to find ways, if `x` itself evaluates to `False`

Answer (score 2):

`or` (and `and`) is a **coalescing operator**; it always returns one of its operands.

```
>>> 1 or False
1
>>> 1 or True
1
>>> 0 or False
False
>>> 0 or True
True
>>> 0 or 'a'
'a'
```

Comment: Sometimes in the code however, the number would be a year, like 2004. 2004 and 2004 == 2004 or True makes no sense to me. It always ended up True because of the last "or True" and caused failure of the unit test. I understand it for 0 and for 1 because 0 == False and 1 == True.

Comment: Non-zero numbers are considered true.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really make sense of that construct either. As you say, it seems like it will always be `True`. I think the intent was to check for a match only if the corresponding field was set, i.e. truthy, but that doesn't do it.

Whoever wrote that probably wanted something like `not x or x==y` but didn't quite get there. It would be expressed more clearly as `x==y if x else True` in today's Python.